# All the columns get updated angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am generating an angular 2 editable table using ngFor but when I try to edit one column all the columns are updated with the same value. I can do it by creating a new component but I have to it by generating new column for the table.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I got it I just have to use track by feature of angular 2